# How to Call Javascript (JS) Code in Manifest.json File for Chrome Plug-In

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, plugins

How do I call Javascript code in a Manifest.json file for a Chrome Plug-In? Calling it the same way as I did for the .html code is not working...

```
"browser_action":{"default_icon":"icon.png", "default_popup": "cocoon.html" }
```

I am learning how to build a Chrome Plug-In that just runs HTML and JavaScript.

My code runs properly when I run the HTML in Chrome as a site. However, when I turned the website into a Chrome Plug-In I called the .html file in my Plug-In manifest.json file by indicating `"default_popup": "cocoon.html"` and thought since the Javascript is called in the HTML it would run properly, but it looks like I need to call it separately in the Manifest.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is it doesn't like onclick and rather need to use **eventlistener** throughout instead.

The error that's happening is this "Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-extensions/rsqvkUYRNqU/R2FROLvVCEYJ

Specifically here as well:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution